# Best practice to use extern struct or extern pointer to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, extern

Say I have 3 files: file1.c, file2.c and globals.h. file1.c and file2.c both include globals.h. file1.c contains a struct that file2.c needs to use. Is it better to make the struct itself extern or create a pointer to the struct and make that pointer extern in globals.h?

Comment: Those two cases do different things, so they're not alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly and your "a struct" is supposed to be a global object (which is a questionable design choice), then I'd do it like this:

**foo.h:**

```
typedef struct foo_struct
{
    /* ... */
} foo;

extern foo the_foo;
```

**foo.c:** [If you like and if it makes sense, you can merge this into file1.c.]

```
#include "foo.h"

foo the_foo = { /* ... */ };
```

**file1.c** and **file2.c**:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "global.h"

/* ... */
```

Comment: I'm new to C. Why is that design choice questionable? What is the best practice to share the same struct across multiple files?

Comment: In most languages, global variables are frowned upon since it makes it harder to debug and test isolated parts of your program when you share global state (among other reasons).

Comment: @MichaelMior does that mean getter functions should be used to pass structs from file to file?

Comment: @user1172282 It means if code functions in file1.c and file2.c need access to a `struct foo` they should likely have it passed by-address (or value) as a parameter rather than relying on an external global. Globals have their place, but you really have to justify it to some people (I being one of them).